# Generate two different random numbers

Tags: c++

I'm going to create a simple "Craps" game using C++

In "Craps", when player throw the dice is not some point that immediatly win or lose, they need to throw it again

But I can't change the dice number when it need to throw again

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void again(int first) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int dice11, dice22, total2;
    do {
        dice11 = (rand() % 6 + 1);
        dice22 = (rand() % 6 + 1);
        total2 = dice11 + dice22;
        cout << "Player throw " << total2 << endl;
        if (total2 == first)
            cout << "Player Win" << endl;
        if (total2 == 7)
            cout << "Player Lose" << endl;
    } while (total2 != first);

}



int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int dice1, dice2,total;
        dice1 = (rand() % 6 + 1);
        dice2 = (rand() % 6 + 1);
        total = dice1 + dice2;

        if (total == 7 || total == 11)
            cout << "Player throw " << total << " Player Win" << endl;
        else
            if (total == 2 || total == 8 || total == 12)
                cout << "Player throw " << total << " Player Lose" << endl;
            else
            {   
                cout << "Player throw " << total << endl;
                again(total);
            }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In program, I already create a function that use "srand()" again, but it still not work

Comment: You should call `srand()` exactly once in your program - the call in `main()` should do it. Calling it in `again()` will just make things worse. If you still have a problem, please edit your question to provide a [mcve] - including explaining exactly what happens versus what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Your second call to `srand` (in the function `again`) might very well be initializing the random number generator to the same seed as the previous call. `time()` counts seconds (mostly, see [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/)). Do not re-initialize the random number generator - unless you want to re-create a previously generated sequence of random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> In program, I already create a function that use "srand()" again, but it still not work

That's because you use `srand()` again.

Do it just once, at the start of your program.

This is explained in [the cppreference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand). Are you programming without documentation?